# ActionMethod for modal button in Layout.cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a LoginController which uses the Layout.cshtml. In my Layout.cshtml I have a button "Login" which shows bootstrap modal to enter username and password and a Login button. My question is where should I set the action method for this button inside the modal which resides in my Layout.cshtml.

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC and I'm using VS 2013. Any help will be appreciated and vote.

Comment: Please tell us, what have you tried so far and include some of your code.

Comment: the MVC action method

Comment: @RPresle: I have an actionmethod in my LoginController named Index with [HttpPost] and I put break point on it but when I click the button login , nothing happens, it doesn't execute where the break point is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my Layout.cshtml I deleted the form tag and use the html helper

```
@using (Html.Beginform())
{
}
```

In my ActionMethod, the parameter names should match the names of the input controls inside my form. And also I added `[HttpPost]` attribute above the head of my action method name.